# Plot in R with one column having more than 1 occurence of values

Tags: r, ggplot2

Basically, I have 3 columns Id, A and B.

Data contains for same value of Id different A and B values.
I need to plot between A and B for same Id.
Any idea how to do it in R ?

Comment: Please provide few lines of your dataset http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you want Id on the x-axis and the values of A and B on the y-axis in the same plot or plot of B vs A?

Comment: If you need a plot A vs B grouped by Id, perhaps `library(ggplot2); ggplot(df1, aes(x=A, y=B))+ geom_point(aes(colour=factor(id)))`

Answer (score 0):

You mean this basic graph:

```
library(ggplot2)

data<-data.frame(ld=c(1,2,3),A=c(10,20,30),B=c(100,200,300))

ggplot(data,aes(x=ld))+
  geom_point(aes(y=A),col="brown1",size=5)+
  geom_point(aes(y=B),col="blue",size=5)+
  ylab("A-B")
```